# Unique Clustered Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a view and I would like to create a unique cluster index on the view:

```
Code:  StartDate  
Wf282  2006-08-09
Wf282  NULL
35895  2016-08-09
```

Is there a way to create a unique ID so I can create a unique Cluster Index on the view as I have several duplicate columns.

Comment: Not a big fan of them, but you may want to consider a Materialized View

Comment: Do your base table(s) queried by the view not have a primary key that you can use?

Comment: I have 3 tables and I have joined the tables via "Code" column in the 3 separate tables. The Column is non-clustered index in 3 tables.